# How do I set firebase security rule

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase real time database. I have an application where users can share posts on the homepage, comment and like on posts, give each other points and comments, and message each other. Users enter the application by registering. There is a mail verification requirement. My app is getting a lot of data downloads. I guess it's because there are no security rules.
How do I set the security rules of this application?

My database ref names:

```
Post
PostLikes
PostComment
PostCommentLikes
PostCategory
PostFollow
OnlineUsers
Users
UsersPost
UsersFriendsList
UsersContact
UsersProfileComments
UsersRatings
UsersNotifications
NotificationsSeens
BlockedUsersList
Tokens
Lastmessage
message
PremiumAccountHolders
```

now my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

When I do this, the home page opens, but when I press the leaderboard class (ref name UsersRatings) for example, the application closes. It says you don't have permission to access. :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

--Update-- Shutdown Error :

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException
Firebase Database error: Permission denied


com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException (DatabaseError.java:230)
com.**.**.ScorBoard$3.onCancelled (ScorBoard.java:141)
com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireCancelEvent (ValueEventRegistration.java:80)
com.google.firebase.database.core.view.CancelEvent.fire (CancelEvent.java:40)
com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java:55)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

---Update--- example closing scorboard (learderboard) class:

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        RatingsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ratings");
        RatingsRef.keepSynced(false);

        RatingsRef.child(currentUserID).child("Ratings").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double sum =  0.0;

                try {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                        Object rating =  map.get("rating");
                        Double pvalue = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(rating));
                        sum += pvalue;



                        Map messageTextBody2 = new HashMap();
             
                       messageTextBody2.put("point", sum);

                        RatingsRef.child(currentUserID).updateChildren(messageTextBody2);


                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
            }
        });

        getScor();


public void getScor(){

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Comments> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comments>()
                        .setQuery(RatingsRef.orderByChild("point").limitToLast(currentpage * total_ITEMS),Comments.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comments,ScorViewHolder> adapter
                =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comments, ScorViewHolder>(options)
        {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ScorBoard.ScorViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comments model) {
                final String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                scorprog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,ProfileClick.class);
                        intent.putExtra("visit_user_id",visit_user_id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                UsersRef.child(visit_user_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")){
                                final String myUsername = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                holder.userName.setText(myUsername);
                            }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                RatingsRef.child(visit_user_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("point")){
                            final String myPoint = dataSnapshot.child("point").getValue().toString();
                            holder.userPoint.setText(myPoint+" "+"Point");
                        }else  {
                            holder.userPoint.setText("0 Point");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ScorBoard.ScorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.scorboard_model_layout,viewGroup,false);
                ScorBoard.ScorViewHolder viewHolder = new ScorBoard.ScorViewHolder(view);
                return  viewHolder;
            }
        };

        adapter.startListening();
        scorreflesh.setRefreshing(false);
        scorrecy.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get when it closes?

Comment: Hi alex, I added the error.

Comment: So you don't have the proper rules. Show us the code that you're using to read the data.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: So you need to read data under `$uid/Ratings`, right?

Comment: can you write the  code? When I typed this "$uid/Ratings" I got this warning: "String can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" ". I am creating security rule for the first time. Sorry for that.

Comment: Where are you getting that?

Comment: In the Firebase rules section